# Plotly: Make_subplots doesn't keep selected colors

Tags: python, plotly

I managed to create  2 subplots from 2 dataframes but it seems that colors I selected have not been kept. Here my code:

```
Worst_20=Worst_deathrate.head(20)
Best_20=Best_recoveredrate.head(20)
fig=make_subplots(rows=1,cols=2,subplot_titles=['Worst Death Rate','Best Recovered Rate'],
                 specs=[[{"type": "bar"}, {"type": "bar"}]])

fi1=px.bar(Worst_20,x=Worst_20.index ,y='death_rate',color=np.log(Worst_20['death_rate']),
           color_continuous_scale=px.colors.sequential.Agsunset)
fig2=px.bar(Best_20,x=Best_20.index,y=Best_20['recovered_rate'],color=np.log(Best_20['recovered_rate']),
           color_continuous_scale=px.colors.sequential.Tealgrn)


fig.add_trace(fig1['data'][0],row=1,col=1)
fig.add_trace(fig2['data'][0],row=1,col=2)
fig.update(layout_coloraxis_showscale=True)

fig.show()
```

Below, as u can see, the outcome doesn't show as set:

[image]

Comment: Please include a sample of your data.

Answer (score 1):

It's a real pain. What you might want to try is something like this:

```
fig.update_layout(coloraxis_autocolorscale=False, coloraxis_colorscale=['blue','lightblue','yellow','orange','darkorange','red'])
```

The crucial part is **coloraxis_autocolorscale=False** that disables default template's colorscale settings. Then you can try to set some custom colorscale, **common** for both your subplots. I didn't find any way to set 2 different scales.